# how to remove/truncate zero from left side of string

Tags: objective-c, string, truncate

```
i am trying to remove zero "0" from left in the string means if string is "0000560352"
```

it will give it to me "560352".
it's dynamically change so if user will enter in textbox like "0560352" then only first zero will remove from string.any idea for this thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is too simple just convert it to NSInteger and then bring back to NSString

```
NSString *str = @"0000560352";
NSInteger i = [str integerValue];
str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a loop or a conversion

```
NSCharacterSet *zeros = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0"];
NSString *nonLeadingZerosString = [@"000560352" stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:zeros];
```

But at the end of the day you want to use a number formatter.